# C++ how to make tuple of ofstreams?

Tags: c++, tuples, ofstream

I have three std::ofstream objects and I placed them in a function like below and use them in main().  I got a lot of error messages when I compiled it, can anybody help me with this?

```
#include<string>
#include<tuple>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

std::tuple<std::ofstream, std::ofstream, std::ofstream>
set_ofstream_tuple() {
   std::ofstream out1("out1.txt", std::ofstream::out);
   out1 << "this is out1.txt" << std::endl;
   std::ofstream out2("out2.txt", std::ofstream::out);
   out2 << "this is out2.txt" << std::endl;
   std::ofstream out3("out3.txt", std::ofstream::out);
   out3 << "this is out3.txt" << std::endl;

   return std::make_tuple(out1, out2, out3);
}

int main() {
  std::ofstream out1, out2, out3;
  std::tie(out1, out2, out3) = set_ofstream_tuple();
  /// make use of there ofstreams more here
}
```

Comment: Please post your error messages, to make other people that would help gain time.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `std::ofstream::out` is the default value for the second argument the `ofstream` constructor. You don't need to write it. `std::ofstream out1("out1.txt");` is sufficient.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are right.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
return std::make_tuple<out1, out2, out3>;
```

is weird. What were you trying to do? :)

[`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) is a *function*, which makes a tuple out of its arguments:

```
return std::make_tuple(std::move(out1), std::move(out2), std::move(out3));
```

*Note the `std::move`, those are required because you can't copy a `std::ofstream`.*

Comment: Throw in three `std::move`s there too.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks, forgot about that :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I still got errors from using std::move() and std::forward_as_tuple().  Is your compiling working with this snippet ?  I used -std=c++11.

Comment: @user3658306 [It works for me using `std::make_tuple`](https://ideone.com/AgvPdJ)

Comment: The first few lines error here...  I used return std::make_tuple(std::move(out1), std::move(out2), std::move(out3));

Comment: @user3658306 And the first line? You can always add the messages to your question

Comment: @Rakete1111 the first couple lines - /share/apps/gcc/4.9.2/include/c++/4.9.2/tuple: In instantiation of 'constexpr std::_Head_base<_Idx, _Head, false>::_Head_base(const _Head&) [with long unsigned int _Idx = 2ul; _Head = std::basic_ofstream<char>]':

Comment: @Rakete1111 I tried to append more errors at the end of the main code, but the formatting was not correct.

Comment: @user3658306 I have no idea why it doesn't compile, maybe ask a new question?

Comment: Would you please post your code in Answer if it compiles ? Thanks.

Comment: @user3658306 [I already posted a link before, here is it again (click me) :)](https://ideone.com/AgvPdJ)

Comment: @Rakete1111 did you use C++11 ? Or other compiler [options]?

Comment: @user3658306 It was compiled with gcc using -std=c++14, but I think it is also valid for C++11

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am still getting the same errors with gcc and -std=c++14.

Comment: @user3658306 This doesn't make sense. You should really consider asking a new question. Comments are typically only for clarification

Comment: @Rakete1111 using std::unique_ptr works for -std=c++14, but I am learning how to get the result variable into the ofstreams.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're copying the non-copyable `ofstream` into the tuple before returning it.

One solution is to move the ofstreams into the tuple before returning:

```
#include<string>
#include<tuple>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

std::tuple<std::ofstream, std::ofstream, std::ofstream>
set_ofstream_tuple() 
{
   std::ofstream out1("out1.txt", std::ofstream::out);
   out1 << "this is out1.txt" << std::endl;
   std::ofstream out2("out2.txt", std::ofstream::out);
   out2 << "this is out2.txt" << std::endl;
   std::ofstream out3("out3.txt", std::ofstream::out);
   out3 << "this is out3.txt" << std::endl;

   return std::make_tuple(std::move(out1), std::move(out2), std::move(out3));
}

int main() {
  std::ofstream out1, out2, out3;
  std::tie(out1, out2, out3) = set_ofstream_tuple();
  /// make use of there ofstreams more here

}
```

proof: [on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wpedantic+-march%3Dnative',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwDwGcAuAncBzAfAKFElkSTRgAcoECjp5kAzdDBAQwFtbx7SQB7Fuy7586OAC4J5KsnFT%2BzTMIA0AAnkTFQzus3blnAigRoA%2BgdaczM6gAoAlGvwBvfGrVsYafhsMcUNQBeP0kJDjYAawQbSnt9JSsOOwAifm8ARgA6NAAPNBS9NDDLYQVvBxV3DxrauvqGuoSdZLTvACYc/MLQhUSyrQqqxpHR%2Bub/VPS0AGYugqKS/s5ytAcHAG5RDy8fADI1aYzg3olsUyQABlw7FpRN6t3%2BA%2Bn2k81ztCQMm7uHne8z0O3hm72KUk%2BSHav389y21SOaiQSDUKTQAAsQIEscC0Nk8gUkSjNAgwHAoFsPK8iaiMTica95ikaSSyRSESCaWjMdjAtM5gTmcjTqTyfCPKxyBgwH4kigtgBfUTgNBqCLgRxqNweCZJXEZdSvQ0gymnNAgBB2I7GtDtG0zJwhEzmUrWWyW/5qAD0PrVUQQahgJkOjDUGIQrBDdzV/Ej6IjCFECqAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

Another solution is to use the tuple as the primary storage during creation:

```
#include<string>
#include<tuple>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

std::tuple<std::ofstream, std::ofstream, std::ofstream>
set_ofstream_tuple() 
{
  auto streams = std::make_tuple(std::ofstream("out1.txt", std::ofstream::out),
                                 std::ofstream("out2.txt", std::ofstream::out),
                                 std::ofstream("out3.txt", std::ofstream::out));

  auto& out1 = std::get<0>(streams);
  auto& out2 = std::get<1>(streams);
  auto& out3 = std::get<2>(streams);

  out1 << "this is out1.txt" << std::endl;
  out2 << "this is out2.txt" << std::endl;
  out3 << "this is out3.txt" << std::endl;

  return streams;
}

int main() {
  std::ofstream out1, out2, out3;
  std::tie(out1, out2, out3) = set_ofstream_tuple();
  /// make use of there ofstreams more here

}
```

As of c++17 we'll be able to avoid the redundant construction of the empty `ofstream`s with the upcoming `std::optional` (demo here using `std::experimental`) :

```
#include<string>
#include<tuple>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

#include <experimental/optional>

std::tuple<std::ofstream, std::ofstream, std::ofstream>
set_ofstream_tuple() 
{
  auto streams = std::make_tuple(std::ofstream("out1.txt", std::ofstream::out),
                                 std::ofstream("out2.txt", std::ofstream::out),
                                 std::ofstream("out3.txt", std::ofstream::out));

  auto& out1 = std::get<0>(streams);
  auto& out2 = std::get<1>(streams);
  auto& out3 = std::get<2>(streams);

  out1 << "this is out1.txt" << std::endl;
  out2 << "this is out2.txt" << std::endl;
  out3 << "this is out3.txt" << std::endl;

  return streams;
}

int main() {
  std::experimental::optional<std::ofstream> out1, out2, out3;
  std::tie(out1, out2, out3) = set_ofstream_tuple();
  /// make use of there ofstreams more here

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first and second solutions do not work for me with either C++11 or C++14 on the compiler version I am using.

Comment: @user3658306 what is the compiler version?

Comment: @user3658306 added a link to godbolt to prove it.

Comment: godbolt shows the same compiling failure as I have gotten.  It is a cool tool ! Thank you for sharing.

Comment: With C++17 you'd use structured bindings instead of `optional` ... `auto [out1, out2, out3] = set_ofstream_tuple();`

Comment: just test with godbolt, gcc/5.1 works with this code I wrote.

Comment: I do not think gcc/4.9.2 have C++17.

Comment: @user3658306 i would strongly suggest that you upgrade to 5.3 (or even 6).

Comment: @RichardHodges Unfortunately, I am not in charge.

Comment: @user3658306 When I used to work for other people I often wondered why companies have someone in charge of preventing progress. It's a terrible false economy to trap a business and its employees into old technology. If nothing else, it forces all the bright guys who want to progress to leave the company. My projects always use the latest stable tools and library versions. If nothing else, it keeps the work interesting and fun. My commiserations.

Comment: @RichardHodges I fully agree. Thanks a lot for spotting the issue.